# Numeric Overflow exception with collection.EXISTS(n) method

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql, ora-01426

I'm getting ORA-01426: numeric overflow when running the following piece of code on Oracle 11g database:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE my_type
    IS
      RECORD
  (
    a NUMBER,
    b VARCHAR2(10) );
TYPE my_table
IS
  TABLE OF my_type INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  my_var my_table;
  my_num1 NUMBER;
  my_num2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
  my_num1 := 1;
  my_num2 := 781301042106240;
  IF NOT my_var.EXISTS(my_num1) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('my num1 works');
  END IF;
  IF NOT my_var.EXISTS(my_num2) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('my num2 works');
  END IF;
END;
```

It appears that EXISTS method can not handle the large number. But shouldn't it accept a NUMBER data type as input? 
Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#CJAEFFID) doesn't help much as it doesn't mention parameter's data type.

Does anyone knows what is max precision that EXISTS can accept?

Comment: Variables declared as BINARY_INTEGER can be assigned values up to 2**31 (2,147,483,647).

Comment: Thanks schurik, you are right this is INDEX BY precision problem. The fix would be to use VARCHAR2 instead of BINARY_INTEGER... TYPE my_table IS TABLE OF my_type INDEX BY VARCHAR2(40);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have used record data type in which you have mentioned a variable with

varchar2(10) now in the third line  (my_var my_table) you are referring a table of record

type but when you have initialized a number   ( my_num2 := 781301042106240;) the precision

is much beyond the variable size in record so you are getting an error please try this:

```
DECLARE

 TYPE my_type

    IS

      RECORD

  (

    a NUMBER,

    b VARCHAR2(10) );

TYPE my_table

IS

  TABLE OF my_type INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  my_var my_table;

  my_num1 NUMBER;

 my_num2 simple_integer :=1078130104;

BEGIN

  my_num1 := 1;

  IF NOT my_var.EXISTS(my_num1) THEN

    dbms_output.put_line('my num1 works');

  END IF;

  IF NOT my_var.EXISTS(my_num2) THEN

    dbms_output.put_line('my num2 works');

  END IF;

END;
```

please revert back if you are not able to follow what i am trying to say or you are not

satisfied with the answer.